# MVC3: Use javascript to clone HTML elements that use models

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, clone, html.dropdownlistfor

Is it possible to use the Javascript method clone() to clone an mvc html element like  dropdown list that is defined using a model?

I have a drop down list with options from a model; and I want to add a similar drop down list when the user clicks on a button. My drop down list is defined as

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="id">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.mymodel)
    </div>
</div>
```

I have added a code like this for my JS

```
var new = document.getElementById('id').cloneNode( true );
document.getElementById( 'parent' ).appendChild( new );
```

But this does not work. 
If I cannot use cloning, how else can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `new` as a variable name -- that's a reserved word in Javascript.  Your approach should work, but just be aware that the `id` attribute has to be unique in an HTML document.

Answer (score -1):

I would use Jquery to do this:

```
 // get the content
 var content= $('#id').html();
 $('#parent').append(content);
```

Keep in mind that the name and id of the element will also gets copied. This might cause conflict when trying to retrieve the items in the element.

Comment: erm...why did I got voted down for this? Is the solution not working? I've verified the solution myself on a test project. Or have I not understand the question correctly?